# Why does the Unity dash lose focus?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

The majority of the time, after logging in to Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit), the Unity launcher seems to default to the wrong focus level. Instead of, for example, the dash always being on top of other already-opened windows and applications, it sits behind them, forcing me to move the other windows to the side so that I can see the dash.

Why doesn't the dash stay on top?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem, but enabling 'KDE Compatibility' in CCSM seemed to fix it for me!